# Unable to find fxml file in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm currently trying to follow a Javafx Tutorial on the web and I have some issues. 
I have a project with 3 different packages. 
Fist one is : ch.makery.address, it contains the Main
Second is : ch.makery.model it's empty for the moment
Third is : ch.makery.view it contains 2 different fxml files wich correspond to two different layouts.
Here is the Main code :

```
`package ch.makery.address;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");

        initRootLayout();

        showPersonOverview();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the root layout.
     */
    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows the person overview inside the root layout.
     */
    public void showPersonOverview() {
        try {
            // Load person overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/PersonOverview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the main stage.
     * @return
     */
    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }}`
```

And here are the errors that it returns :

---

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at ch.makery.adress.MainApp.initRootLayout(MainApp.java:35)
    at ch.makery.adress.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application ch.makery.adress.MainApp
```

---

For what I understand of it, it appears to be a problem when locating the fxml files. But I don't understand why.
If anybody can help me on it, it would be perfect
Thanks

(Sorry if there is any mistakes in my English it's not my mother tongue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Main` is in `ch.makery.address` and your fxml in `ch.makery.view` then this is wrong:

```
view/RootLayout.fxml
```

as it tries to load the file from `ch.makery.address.view`.

Try

```
../view/RootLayout.fxml
```

instead. (Same for `PersonOverview`)

Comment: So how should I change it ? Should I just change it to ("RootLayout.fxml")?

Comment: Seems like it solve the problem for that but obviously it's not the only one... It still not working.

Comment: Maybe you should take a better tutorial ;-)

Comment: I don't have any others. And it seems to be a good one I think the problem is coming from me.

Comment: No, there are tons of bad tutorials on the net. Just google for a different one.

Comment: I use that one do you think it's a bad one ? http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/

Comment: It is very detailed, which is good at first sight. They provide the sources for download. Try to get it running, this should save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

It is the path to the *fxml* files that is wrong in that tutorial had the same issue. Using the `../` to move up one directory should work to fix paths to the *fxml* files.